# DOM tree structure

Tags: html, xml, dom

I have a line of HTML source code like:

```
<span class="price proPrice" itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD">US $<span itemprop="lowPrice">9.76</span> - <span itemprop="highPrice">13.26</span>  </span>
```

I wonder if the corresponding DOM tree should be:

```
      < s  p  a  n  >
      /     |     |   \
   [US $] <span> [-]  <span> 
            |           |
          [9.76]     [13.26]
```

Where "[ ]" contains the "#text" nodes. The above code displays as `US $9.76 - 13.26`

I'm learning the DOM tree structure myself but I get kind of confused here. Also I'd like to know whether leaf nodes can only be text nodes or img nodes? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks about right (the attributes, and white space after the last inner `<span>` would also appear).

> Also I'd like to know whether leaf nodes can only be text nodes or img nodes?

Any node that does not contain another node, eg. a `<br \>` will be a leaf node.